# What is the purpose of the "term_id" column in the "wp_term_taxonomy" table?

Tags: database, taxonomy, terms

The table below shows some example rows from a "wp_term_taxonomy" database table. Notice that values of the "term_taxonomy_id" and "term_id" columns are exactly the same. What is the use of the "term_id" column if it has the same value as the "term_taxonomy_id" column?

[image: Example of rows in the wp_term_taxonomy table]

In what cases will the value of the "term_taxonomy_id" and "term_id" columns differ? Can a given term belong to more than one taxonomy? If so, could you give a concrete example where this is useful?

WordPress version: 6.0.1

Comment: The current [schema](https://bit.ly/3JyLZow) does support assigning the same term to multiple taxonomies, e.g. term `1` could have another entry in the term_taxonomy table, where the taxonomy could be `post_tag` or anything other than `category`. However, WordPress would never do that, so a term would only ever have one taxonomy. And the `term_id` is actually mandatory because the table (`wp_term_taxonomy`) is used to place a term in a specific taxonomy, hence it needs to know what the term is. The terms table is simply used to store basic details like name and slug. Were you aware of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions of WordPress prior to 4.2 terms could belong to multiple taxonomies. This is no longer the case and in WordPress 4.2 or newer new terms cannot belong to multiple taxonomies and any existing terms that belong to multiple taxonomies are split into multiple terms whenever they are updated.

You can read this post for an introduction to the change from before it was made: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/

There is also this article which describes the splitting process: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/split-terms-wp-4-2/

So unless you are dealing with pre-4.2 data the values of these columns should always be the same.

Comment: note this also impacted something called global terms which is no longer supported, where a multisite could share terms

Comment: Does this mean that the there is now no use for the separation between the "wp_terms" and "wp_term_taxonomy" tables, except for backward-compatibility reasons? In other words, can the fields in the "wp_terms" and "wp_term_taxonomy" tables be combined into a single table if backward-compatibility is not an issue?

Comment: Don’t mess with core tables. There’s nothing to gain. You might not have any data that has different values for these columns but they still exist and different themes and plugins could still use either column, and there is very likely WordPress code that expects both columns to exist even if they’re not utilised separately anymore. This is textbook premature optimisation. There are doubtless many more things that are actually your responsibility that would yield better gains than messing with this.

Comment: Thank you. i now know that the change was made to fix the WordPress bug where editing a category would affect a tag that has the same name as the category.

Answer (score 0):

The **term_id** is the ID of a term in the terms table. A term is a word that can belong in any taxonomy (category, tag, custom taxonomy), and taxonomy can contain the same term. For example, you decide to have a term by the name of shoes; the term_id is a number that represents this word. The number is independent of the taxonomies within which you list shoes.

Additionally, the **term_taxonomy_id** is the unique ID for the term+taxonomy pair. If you use the term shoes as both a post tag and a category, the term_taxonomy_id will be different for both.

Moreover, both have an auto-increment in the table structure, so as you add a post that includes a term and a taxonomy (even uncategorized), both the term_id and term_taxonomy_id will increase automatically, and **in all but a few cases, they will be the same**.

You use the term_id value for functions that expect a category ID. The term_taxonomy_id can serve as a query variable; otherwise, it is rarely used.

Comment: "in all but a few cases, they will be the same" — What are those few cases?

Comment: I cannot remember when, but I think the last time they could be different was back in version 4, quite some time ago. If you are thinking about combining them into one record, I advise not to combine term_id and term_taxonomy_id  into one record.